# Is there something wrong with my GDB?

Tags: c++, gdb

My program hangs **hard** (nigh freezes my whole computer), and I'm trying to figure out where it's happening. I've gone through some *gdb* tutorials and other things—and followed them pretty well. Whenever I see *gdb* output, though, it's somewhat clean and readable (that is, its output seems to at least relate to the file which it is debugging).

Here's a *small* chunk of my gdb's output:

```
23  std::map<std::string, int> Item::getStats() { return enhancements_; };
(gdb) step
Python Exception <class 'ValueError'> Cannot find type const std::map<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int, std::less<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, int> > >::_Rep_type: 
map (__x=std::map with 2 elements, this=0x7fffffffd0c0)
    at src/item.cpp:23
23  std::map<std::string, int> Item::getStats() { return enhancements_; };
(gdb) step
_Rb_tree (__x=..., this=0x7fffffffd0c0) at src/item.cpp:23
23  std::map<std::string, int> Item::getStats() { return enhancements_; };
(gdb) step
_Rb_tree_impl (__a=<optimized out>, __comp=..., this=0x7fffffffd0c0)
    at /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_tree.h:474
474         _M_header(), _M_node_count(0)
(gdb) step
475       { _M_initialize(); }
(gdb) step
_M_initialize (this=0x7fffffffd0c0)
    at /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_tree.h:484
484         this->_M_header._M_left = &this->_M_header;
(gdb) 
485         this->_M_header._M_right = &this->_M_header;
(gdb) step
_Rb_tree (__x=..., this=0x7fffffffd0c0)
    at /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_tree.h:674
674     if (__x._M_root() != 0)
(gdb) step
_M_root (this=0x7fffffffd038)
    at /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_tree.h:498
498       { return this->_M_impl._M_header._M_parent; }
```

Is there something up with my gdb or is this how it's generally *supposed* to read? I'm not seeing anything from the other header files or code outside of main.cpp. Only three of the above lines seem to relate to my code at all.

Edit: 
I'm using G++ 4.9.2 and GDB 7.7.1 on Ubuntu 14.04 w/ Python 2.7.6

The output of 'where' is:

```
(gdb) where
#0  _int_malloc (av=0x7ffff7840760 <main_arena>, bytes=48) at malloc.c:3775
#1  0x00007ffff75047b0 in __GI___libc_malloc (bytes=48) at malloc.c:2891
#2  0x00007ffff7aebf18 in operator new(unsigned long) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#3  0x00000000004016f7 in allocate (__n=1, this=0x7fffffffd0c0) at /usr/include/c++/4.9/ext/new_allocator.h:104
#4  allocate (__n=1, __a=...) at /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/alloc_traits.h:357
#5  _M_get_node (this=0x7fffffffd0c0) at /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_tree.h:385
#6  _M_create_node<std::pair<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, int> const&> (this=0x7fffffffd0c0)
    at /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_tree.h:417
#7  _M_clone_node (__x=0xa7b82fa0, this=0x7fffffffd0c0) at /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_tree.h:445
#8  std::_Rb_tree<std::string, std::pair<std::string const, int>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::string const, int> >, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, int> > >::_M_copy (this=this@entry=0x7fffffffd0c0, __x=0xa7b82fa0, __p=0xa7b82fa0, 
    __p@entry=0x7fffffffd0c8) at /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_tree.h:1219
#9  0x0000000000401cc5 in _Rb_tree (__x=..., this=0x7fffffffd0c0) at /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_tree.h:676
Python Exception <class 'ValueError'> Cannot find type const std::map<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int, std::less<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, int> > >::_Rep_type: 
#10 map (__x=std::map with 2 elements, this=0x7fffffffd0c0) at /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_map.h:183
#11 Item::getStats (this=0x7fffffffd020) at src/item.cpp:23
#12 0x00000000004011a5 in main () at src/main.cpp:26
```

I can walk up and down the stack, backtrace, set breaks, and things like this—but all the output is similar in its format. I was expecting to see something a little cleaner, with more relevance to the code that I'm debugging. Something like what's in [this](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~gilpin/tutorial/) tutorial:

```
Breakpoint 1, LinkedList<int>::remove (this=0x40160, 
    item_to_remove=@0xffbef014) at main.cc:52
52      Node<T> *marker = head_;
(gdb) step
53      Node<T> *temp = 0;  // temp points to one behind as we iterate
(gdb) 
55      while (marker != 0) {
(gdb) 
56        if (marker->value() == item_to_remove) {
(gdb) 
Node<int>::value (this=0x401b0) at main.cc:30
30    const T& value () const { return value_; }
(gdb) 
LinkedList<int>::remove (this=0x40160, item_to_remove=@0xffbef014)
    at main.cc:75
75        marker = 0;  // reset the marker
(gdb) 
76        temp = marker;
(gdb) 
77        marker = marker->next();
(gdb) 
Node<int>::next (this=0x0) at main.cc:28
28    Node<T>* next () const { return next_; }
(gdb) 

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
Node<int>::next (this=0x0) at main.cc:28
28    Node<T>* next () const { return next_; }
(gdb)
```

Mine seems unintelligible compared to that.

Comment: `Python Exception` suggests that you either have a broken GDB install, or G++ that is too new for your GDB. Please share all the relevant versions. It is not too clear what are expecting to see. What GDB `where` command does for you? Can you walk up and down the stack with `up` and `down`?

Comment: @n.m I added some info—thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Did gdb output any error messages at the beginning? There's a known (fixable) bug with Ubuntu 14.04 where you'll get  `File "/usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19-gdb.py", line 63, in <module> from libstdcxx.v6.printers import register_libstdcxx_printers ImportError: No module named 'libstdcxx'` and the STL-friendly gdb scripts don't get loaded.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I don't have the output anymore, but I think I do remember seeing that

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why your program freezes your whole computer, but the problem is obvious right here:

```
75        marker = 0;  // reset the marker
76        temp = marker;
77        marker = marker->next();
```

If you ignore line 76, and just read the code, it appears to be clearly wrong. Perhaps you meant to write:

```
marker = marker->next();
```

Comment: This is why I wonder if there's something wrong with my gdb—that isn't my code, haha. When I said "Only three of the above lines seem related to my code," I actually mean *only* three lines. The rest is foreign to me.

Comment: @AmagicalFishy I am not sure what you mean by "foreign to me". The three lines are coming from `main.cc`, which is almost certainly application code, not library code.

Comment: Oh! You're looking at the very last *gdb* output—that's an example from another tutorial. I put it there to show what I expected to see (that's the *legible* example of someone else's *gdb*. Mine outputs what is above that).